# Jsplumb Hide all connectors except 1

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am using Jsplumb to Design Workflows. Some of the workflows can be extremely complex and the multiple connectors can make it difficult to figure out which connector is connected to which task. In order to fix this/show a guide, I would like to hide all connectors when a connection is clicked and only show the clicked connection.

My code for adding connectors is like this:

//Add a Task
            function addTask(id) {

```
            $('  <div class="window task node Btn Color-Light BR-3 BS-20  Engrave" id="' + id + '"' +
                //Append to Base HTML 
                ' data-nodetype="task" style="left:530px; top:530px; width:230px;">').appendTo('#' + htmlBase).html($(("#WfTask0"))[0].innerHTML);

            var taskSourceConnectorEndpoint = {
                isSource: true,
                isTarget: false,
                maxConnections: 1,
                anchor: [0.5, 1, 0, 1, 20, 0, "task_end endpoint"],

            };
            //Failure Anchor
            var leftDecisionConnectorEndpoint = {
                isSource: true,
                isTarget: false,
                maxConnections: -1,
                anchor: [0, 0.5, 0, 1, 18, 72, "left_dec_start startpoint"],
                paintStyle: { fillStyle: 'transparent', lineWidth: 5, },
                endpoint: ["Dot", { width: 25, height: 25 }],
                endpointStyle: { fillStyle: 'rgb(185,61,255)' },
                connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], gap: 10, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
                cornerRadius:50,
                connectorStyle: {
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    strokeStyle: "#B93DFF"
                },
                overlays: [
                    [
                        "Arrow", {
                            width: 10,
                            length: 10,
                            foldback: 1,
                            location: 1,
                            id: "arrow"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            };

            //Success Anchor
            var rightDecisionConnectorEndpoint = {
                isSource: true,
                isTarget: false,
                maxConnections: -1,
                anchor: [1, 0.5, 1, 0, -16, 75, "right_dec_start startpoint"],
                paintStyle: { fillStyle: 'transparent', lineWidth: 5, },
                endpoint: ["Dot", { width: 25, height: 25 }],
                endpointStyle: {},
                connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], gap: 10, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
                //cssClass: "aRedEndpoint",
                connectorStyle: {
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    strokeStyle: "lightgreen"
                },
                overlays: [
                    [
                        "Arrow", {
                            width: 10,
                            length: 10,
                            foldback: 1,
                            location: 1,

                            id: "arrow"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            };

            var taskTargetConnectorEndpoint = {
                isSource: false,
                isTarget: true,
                maxConnections: -1,
                anchor: [0.5, 0, 0, -1, 6.5, 11.7, "task_end endpoint "],
                paintStyle: { fillStyle: 'transparent' },
                endpoint: ["Rectangle", { width: 25, height: 25 }]
            };

            //Add Anchors to the Task
            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                $('#' + id),
                rightDecisionConnectorEndpoint
            );

            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                $('#' + id),
                leftDecisionConnectorEndpoint
            );

            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                $('#' + id),
                taskTargetConnectorEndpoint
            );

            jsPlumb.draggable($('#' + id));

            //Reposition Elements
            posY = +posY + +spacer;
            repositionElement(id, posX, posY);
         return id;
        }
```

I am able to bind the click event and get the connection but I am lost at that point.

```
  jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {
                    //   $('._jsPlumb_connector').addClass('clsActiveConnector');
                });
```

This question is possibly related to 
[jsPlumb: How do I select a specific connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346942/jsplumb-how-do-i-select-a-specific-connector)

However, I think I am trying to do a select inverse type of situation in this case...

Any suggestion is very welcome...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think that within the click event method that you have there, you will have to iterate through all window elements and call jsPlumb.hide() (see http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/miscellaneous-examples.html).

```
$( ".window" ).each(function( index, item ) {
   jsPlumb.hide(item);
});
```

Then you would make the connection you selected visible:

```
connection.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I always find it amazing when someone can write code without testing and it works right off the bat. Thank you so much...Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more generic way :

```
$.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function(idx, connection) {
    connnection.setVisible(false);
});
```

Above snippet will hide all connections. Below is how it fits in your code.

```
 jsPlumb.bind('click', function (conn, e) {
    $.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function(idx, connection) {
        connnection.setVisible(false);
    });
   conn.setVisible(true);
 });
```

Related Docs

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/miscellaneous-examples.html

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/Connection.html#method_setVisible

Comment: @Coding_smart, this works as well, and gives me additional hooks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may find themselves in a similar situation asking same question, this is my final code:

```
 jsPlumb.bind('click', function (conn, e) {
                    $.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
                        if (connection.isVisible()) {//hide
                            connection.setVisible(false);
                        } else {//show
                            connection.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                    conn.setVisible(true);
                });
```

Somehow simply using toggle didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In current versions there are query methods for connections and endpoints, so no need for a loop,

> and the return value is an object that supports most operations that you can perform on an Endpoint.

See the docs here: http://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/querying.html

Example, hide all connections:

```
jsPlumb.select().setVisible(false);
```